# a4j:poll start polling after JSF rendering

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to use a4j:poll to load content in my view *after* the rendering of JSF is done, in order to increase rendering speed of the view itself. I think it is a pretty common taks to deliver the page and then start polling content afterwards. However, if I have a construct like this:

```
     <h:form>
      <a:region>
        <a:poll id="feed" reRender="feedReader" interval="100"/>
        <a:outputPanel id="feedReader">
          <h2>
            <a  href="#{feedReader.link}">
              <h:outputText value="#{feedReader.title}" />
            </a>
          </h2>
          <h:outputText value="#{feedReader.teaser}" />
        </a:outputPanel>
      </a:region>
    </h:form>
```

Everything inside the `a:outputPanel` will be rendered on the initial page request. How can I surpress this behaviour?

Comment: I think you will find that the polling does begin after the JSF view has been rendered, do you mean after the DOM has fully loaded?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out of the box that allows this, you could just set a bean property that activates the polling via a javascript (or jQuery in this case) command when the page has fully loaded, see example below,

Or alternatively you could create a counter in the polling action so that the first few 'polls' are ignored

Unless you have some seriously big resources being loaded into the page it shouldn't make much difference

```
<h:form>
  <a:region>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="enablePollJs" action="#{yourBean.enablePoll} reRender="feed" />
    <a:poll id="feed" reRender="feedReader" interval="100" enabled="#{yourBean.pollEnabled}" />
    <a:outputPanel id="feedReader">
      <h2>
        <a  href="#{feedReader.link}">
          <h:outputText value="#{feedReader.title}" />
        </a>
      </h2>
      <h:outputText value="#{feedReader.teaser}" />
    </a:outputPanel>
  </a:region>
</h:form>

//Then add this to your javascript / header
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        enablePollJs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because of the info that there is no such thing. What I found is this: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html which might be helpful.